# Does the variance of these random variables tend to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis, variance, integral-inequality

Let $X$ be a probability space, and let $F:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^2$ strictly convex function. Suppose that $F''$ is an everywhere **positive strictly decreasing**  function, and that $\lim_{x \to \infty} F''(x)=0$.

Let $g_n:X \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ be measurable, with constant expectations $\int_X g_n=c>0$, and suppose that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X F(g_n)-F(\int_X g_n)=0.$$

> Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X (g_n-c)^2=0$?
>
> ---

A sharpened form of Jensen inequality implies that
$$
\int_X F(g_n)-F(\int_X g_n) \ge (\inf_{x}\frac{F''(x)}{2}) \int_X (g_n-c)^2.
$$
This naive estimate does not help since $\inf_{x} F''(x)=0$.

My intuition is that to have a small "Jensen gap" requires $g_n$ to obtain very high values on a domain with large measure, in order to stay at the region where $F''$ is small. This should be incompatible with the constraint $E(g_n)=c$. (More precisely $g_n$ will have to be below $c$ on a non-negligible domain, where $F''$ is bounded from below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. For simplicity take $c=1$. Take $F(x) = e^{-x}$ for all $x \geq 0$ (so $F''(x)=F(x)$ for all $x \geq 0$).  For $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define random variables $Y_n$ by
$$ Y_n = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} & \mbox{ with prob $1-1/n$}\\
1+ \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}} & \mbox{ with prob $1/n$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then

- $E[Y_n]=1$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[F(Y_n)] = F(1)$.
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(Y_n-1)^2]=1$.

---

On the other hand, if $Y_n$ are uniformly bounded for all $n$, so that $Y_n(\omega) \in [0,M]$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and all $\omega$ in the sample space, then it is true because $F:[0,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is **strongly convex** with parameter $F''(M)>0$: 
$$ F(x) \geq F(c) + F'(c)(x-c) + \frac{F''(M)}{2}(x-c)^2 \quad \forall x \in [0,M]$$
So for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have 
$$ F(Y_n) \geq F(c) + F'(c)(Y_n-c) + \frac{F''(M)}{2}(Y_n-c)^2   $$
Taking expectations of both sides and using $E[Y_n]=c$ gives
$$ E[F(Y_n)] \geq F(c) + \frac{F''(M)}{2}E[(Y_n-c)^2] \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Taking the limit of both sides as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and using $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[F(Y_n)] = F(c)$ gives
$$ 0 \geq \frac{F''(M)}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(Y_n-c)^2] $$
and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[(Y_n-c)^2]=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great counter-example (I also liked the clean treatment of the bounded case, although I was aware of it). One more question: Do you think a counter-example is possible if $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)=\infty$, no matter how fast $F$ grows? (In your example, you used $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)=0$, in order to achieve $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[F(Y_n)] = F(1)$. However, it seems to me that by sufficiently decreasing the probability that $Y_n$ attains the very high value, this could be generalized to these case as well).

Comment: You can take the same random variables and use $F(x)=x+e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks. One last question: do you think that the "discrete nature" of your example plays any crucial role here? That is, can we build an example where the range of each $Y_n$ is an interval $I_n \subseteq \mathbb R$? I guess that we can "smooth out" your example, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what the criteria for smoothing out would be.  But certainly you can approximate the discrete  variables $X_n$  by $\tilde{X}_n$, which have continuous CDF functions, and get similar examples.